# Object reference not set to an instance of an object changing connection string in app.config from code

Tags: .net, vb.net, config

Please see the code below:

```
Public Sub GetConnectionString(Dim strCon As String)
            Dim stringtochange As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GeniedbConnection").ConnectionString 'line 2
            Dim configFile As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
            Dim connectionStringsSection As ConnectionStringsSection
            connectionStringsSection = CType(configFile.GetSection("GeniedbConnection"), ConnectionStringsSection)
            connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings("GeniedbConnection").ConnectionString = strCon 'Line 6
            configFile.Save()
        End Sub
```

I am trying to change the connection string in the app.config.  Line 2 returns the current connection string.  Line 6 throws an exception: `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  Why is this?

Comment: see this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131382/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-app-config

Comment: It is because an object reference is not set to an instance of an object. There's a ton of similar questions on SO, and most of them end up giving the same, correct, advice. Debug your code, see which object reference is not set, and figure out where to go from that.

Comment: I agree with Lasse. There's a question devoted to this topic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 2

```
Dim stringtochange As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GeniedbConnection").ConnectionString
```

is different with line 6

```
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings("GeniedbConnection").ConnectionString = strCon
```

> ConfigurationManager != connectionStringsSection

either of these is null, `connectionStringsSection`, `connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings("GeniedbConnection")`